# Angularjs, select option first is always blank untill selection

Tags: angularjs

When I use select option, the first option of ng-option shows always blank till I select the value.
I have tried option also:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="userDetails.selectedtimezone">
 <option ng-repeat="selecttimezonelist in timezones" ng-selected="userDetails.selectedtimezone == selecttimezonelist.id"  value="{{selecttimezonelist.id}}">{{selecttimezonelist.timezone}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Add a plunkr showing your code.

Comment: U might wanna add  <option value="">Select</option>, that will restrict the blank option.And select option should be there for standard dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By angular way

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="userDetails.selectedtimezone" ng-init="selecttimezonelist = timezones[0]">
    <option ng-repeat="selecttimezonelist in timezones" ng-selected="userDetails.selectedtimezone == selecttimezonelist.id"  value="{{selecttimezonelist.id}}">{{selecttimezonelist.timezone}}</option>
</select>
```

And then use css

```
select option:empty {
    display:none
}
```

Comment: It's doubtful, that this example is "by angular way". Using ng-init, hidding empty option with css, neglecting ng-options directive, unnecessary `ng-selected`. I consider this answer as wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will usually auto fill in the first option of a drop down menu with a blank value if it hasn't been initialized to a value or if you have set it to a value that is not within the list of values it can select from.

You should take a look at what value you are initializing its variable to or, if you haven't yet, initialize the variable to one of the values in the list to select from.